# SQL Server 2008 : Varchar to Datetime conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `datetime` column `ArrivalDateTime` which is stored as a `varchar` value.

Let's say if the value is `20161212093256`, I want the output to be `2016-12-12 09:32:56`.

I could get the date part in datetime format as below.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), LEFT('20161212093256', 8))
```

This returns the output as `2016-12-15 00:00:00`.

I tried the following query to get the time part as well.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, LEFT('20161212093256', 8)) + ' ' + 
    CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT('20161212093256', 6))
```

But this throws an error:

> The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator

How can I get both date and time part in `datetime` format?

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) article.

Comment: Thanks mate for the pointer. Unfortunately I have to make use of the column created by someone else. I cant change its datatype now.

Comment: @turbo88 you can't simply ignore this design bug, as it affect both indexing, querying and performance. By using an arbitrary  string instead of a date, you disable all date-related query optimizations. You'll have to convert any date criteria to this arbitrary format before querying. You won't be able to use any date-related functions without parsing. And finally, the query engine will have to process and pass every single result row when it could use set-based operations or indexes that included the date column. This will result in a huge performance penalty

Comment: @turbo88 consider adding a persisted computed column that parses the string column and returns an actual datetime. You can apply indexes to persisted computed columns and parsing will only be performed when the text column changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the date component first and convert it to `DATETIME` and then get the time component and convert it to `DATETIME` also. Finally, *add* the two results:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('20161212093256', 8)) +
    CONVERT(DATETIME,
        LEFT(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6), 2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6), 3, 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6), 2)
    )
```

---

To further explain, the result first conversion is the date component:

```
2016-12-12 00:00:00.000
```

The second conversion is the time component, but when you convert it to `DATETIME` it adds it to the 0 date or `'1900-01-01'`, so the result is:

```
1900-01-01 09:32:56.000
```

Then, you add both `DATETIME`s to get:

```
2016-12-12 09:32:56.000
```

---

To get rid of the ms component:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('20161212093256', 8)) +
    CONVERT(DATETIME,
        LEFT(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6), 2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6), 3, 2) + ':00'
    )
```

Comment: Brilliant. Is there any way I can ignore the milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @V_STR VARCHAR(20) = '20161212093256'
SELECT  CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,LEFT(@V_STR,8) +' '+      --date
                SUBSTRING(@V_STR,9,2)+':'+              --hour
                SUBSTRING(@V_STR,11,2)+':'+             --minute
                SUBSTRING(@V_STR,13,2)) AS  DATE_TIME   --second
```

Comment: It displays date and time in 2 separate columns. I want them in single column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select concat(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT('20161212093256', 8)) , ' ' , CONVERT(TIME,  substring(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6),1,2)+ ':'  + substring(RIGHT('20161212093256', 4),1,2) + ':' +RIGHT('20161212093256', 2)))
```

above will display time with miliseconds, below without miliseconds

```
select concat(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT('20161212093256', 8)) , ' ' , substring(RIGHT('20161212093256', 6),1,2)+ ':'  + substring(RIGHT('20161212093256', 4),1,2) + ':' +RIGHT('20161212093256', 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20161212093256', 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-'), 11, 0, ' '), 14, 0, ':'), 17, 0, ':')
```